# Ruby gems in stand-alone ruby scripts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

This is a really basic ruby gems question. I'm familiar with writing simple ruby scripts like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'time'
t = Time.at(123)
puts t
```

Now I'd like to use my own ruby gem in my script. In my rails project I can simply `require 'my_gem'`. However this doesn't work in a stand-alone script. **What's the best/proper way to use my own gem in a stand-alone ruby script?**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should be able to simply require it directly in recent versions of Ruby.

```
# optional, also allows you to specify version
gem 'chronic', '~>0.6'

# just require and use it
require 'chronic'
puts Chronic::VERSION  # yields "0.6.7" for me
```

If you are still on Ruby 1.8 (which does not require RubyGems by default), you will have to explicitly put this line above your attempt to load the gem:

```
require 'rubygems'
```

Alternatively, you can invoke the Ruby interpreter with the flag `-rubygems` which will have the same effect.

See also:

- http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3#page70
- http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/4

Answer (score 8):

You could use something like this. It will install the gem if it's not already installed:

```
def load_gem(name, version=nil)
  # needed if your ruby version is less than 1.9
  require 'rubygems'

  begin
    gem name, version
  rescue LoadError
    version = "--version '#{version}'" unless version.nil?
    system("gem install #{name} #{version}")
    Gem.clear_paths
    retry
  end

  require name
end

load_gem 'your_gem'
```

Answer (score 6):

It is to be noted that `bundler` itself can deal with this. It's particularly interesting since `bundler` ships with Ruby by default since version 2.6, and you don't need to install it manually anymore.

The idea is:

1. to require `bundler/inline` at the top of your script,
2. to use the `gemfile` method, and declare the gems you need inside a block, like you'd do in a `Gemfile`,
3. after the end of this section, your gems are available!

For instance:

```
require 'bundler/inline'

gemfile do
  source 'https://rubygems.org'
  gem 'rainbow'
end

# From here on, rainbow is available so I can 
# print colored text into my terminal

require 'rainbow'
puts Rainbow('This will be printed in red').red
```

The official documentation can be found on [bundler website: bundler in a single file ruby script](https://bundler.io/v2.0/guides/bundler_in_a_single_file_ruby_script.html)

Answer (score 3):

Installing gems with something like the following should work. Be mindful of whether gems should be installed as part of system ruby or a user's.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'

def install_gem(name, version=Gem::Requirement.default)
  begin
    gem name, version
  rescue LoadError
    print "ruby gem '#{name}' not found, " <<
      "would you like to install it (y/N)? : "
    answer = gets
    if answer[0].downcase.include? "y"
      Gem.install name, version
    else
      exit(1)
    end
  end
end

# any of the following will work...
install_gem 'activesupport'
install_gem 'activesupport', '= 4.2.5'
install_gem 'activesupport', '~> 4.2.5'

# require as normal (since not all gems install & require with same name) ...
require 'active_support/all'

...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question right, but perhaps you don't have a gem, even if you write it (you are a beginner, so perhaps you misunderstood the concept of gems).

Just to be sure: You have a gemspec for your gem? If not, then you have no gem, but a single script.

When you want your own script inside another script, you may just do:

```
require 'my_script'
```

With ruby 1.8 this works fine, if `my_script.rb` is in the same folder as your main script. With ruby 1.9+ you can use:

```
require_relative 'my_script'
```

There is no need of a gem in this case.

Comment: It is a gem. It's part of a larger rails project. I'd prefer to not load the entire rails project just to use this gem in my script.