# "No available formula for gcc46" while installing Ruby 1.9.3 on OS X with RVM:

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, homebrew

I have Homebrew installed, I'm trying to install RVM with:

```
rvm install 1.9.3-head
```

and I get this error:

```
Installing required packages:gcc46
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install gcc46',
please read /Users/mike/.rvm/log/1384918134_ruby-1.9.3-head/package_install_gcc46.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 1
```

`brew doctor` says I'm ready to brew.

In the log I see:

> Error: Download failed: ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/gmp-4.3.2.tar.bz2

Comment: Why are you installing 1.9.3-head? That’s a pre-release version of an older version… If you’re starting out go with the latest release: 2.0.0-p247.

Comment: Thanks Andrew I'll go with 2.0.0-p247, I read some post warning against the bundled OSX Ruby so 1.9.3 was purely to see how rvm is used.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Ruby 1.9.3+ supports compiling with Clang (which you do have) instead of GCC, so make RVM compile with Clang instead:

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```

Answer (score 4):

When I upgraded to mavericks from mountain lion it somehow started ignoring my dev-tools (like gcc, etc.) try

```
xcode-select --install
```

also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216865/how-to-install-command-line-tools-on-osx-mavericks)

Answer (score 0):

When upgraded to OSX 10.12 and installing ruby 2.3.1 these steps fixed the issue.

```
 brew install homebrew/versions/gcc46
```

if there are any linking issues related to any lib please follow the instructions for example

```
brew link --overwrite libtool
brew link --overwrite libgpg-error
```

Once the installation of gcc46 is successful you could

```
rvm install 2.3.1
```